# Не могу записать число больше одного 1 млрд

Tags: mysql, drupal

при настройке, создал числовое поле, в которое будут вноситься целые числа, все работало прекрасно, пока я не попробовал внести число больше 10 млн, выдало ошибку, и в журнале было сказано тыкайтесь в конкретную таблицу БД, в конкретное поле, типа число мое слишком велико "ну ладно" - подумал я - "наверное разряд большой" нашел это поле в БД и и действительно размер поля стоял 10, я изменил его на 200, то есть теперь как я понимаю в поле можно вносить 200 значные числа, но помогло слабо, в поле можно вписывать только 999 999 999. на моем скрине оно последнее, может быть нужно тип поменять, если да то на какой? ведь и так "натуральные" стоит. Мне кажется тут вопрос не в cms а именно в ДБ и в том что именно в настройках ограничения на поле наложены[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Comment: @strangeqargo а что "о боже" хорошо, когда понимаете, а я с этим в первый раз столкнулся, проблему вроде бы понятно изложил, если можете опишите по-русски (в ответе), что не так, в общем то из статья я понял что формат можно поменять на bigint чтобы в поле помещалось большее количество информации

Comment: вам нужно слегка подкачать свои знания по архитектуре компьютера, это будет очень полезно. поскольку int/float/double/ и тд. очень часто встречаются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поле 200 в `INT(200)` относится лишь к форматированию вывода в консольной утилите mysql. Т.е. при консольном выводе в результирующих таблицах под поле будет отводится столько символов. Обычно нет надобности указывать это значение больше 11.

Разрядность числа определяется типом столбца. Например тип `INT` может хранить значения 2 в степени 32, так как под него отводится 4 байта, каждый их которых хранит 8 бит. 4 * 8 = 32. Таким образом, для беззнакового целого числа вы можете хранить в `INT(11) UNSIGNED` значения в диапазоне от 0 до 4 294 967 296. Если атрибут `UNSIGNED` не указан, по мимо числа потребуется один разряд на хранение знака, т.е. вместо 32 бит, у вас остается только 31. Таким образом, для чисел допускающих использование знака, вы может хранить значения в диапазоне от -2 147 483 648 до 2 147 483 647.

Если вам нужен больший диапазон, лучше ориентироваться на значение `BIGINT`, под которое отводится 8 байт, т.е. 2 в степени 64. Таким образом вы можете хранить значения в диапазоне от -9 223 372 036 854 775 808 до 9 223 372 036 854 775 807.

Если же вы оперируете ценой, возможно вам больше подойдет тип данных `DECIMAL`, который специально создавался для оперирования денежными единицами. Данный тип задается в формате `DECIMAL(10,5)`. Здесь 10 значение отводимое подо все число, а 5 - количество знаков после запятой. Данный тип исключительно точный по сравнению с другими вещественными типами (`DOUBLE`, `FLOAT`), однако, более медленный в обработке, так как хранится он в виде строки, которая обрабатывается медленнее чисел. Зато вы можете хранить числа с количеством десятичных разрядов вплоть до 65536.

Comment: Все так и было, но кроме того размер поля был ограничен в 2х таблицах а я правил в 1 поэтому ничего не получалось)